# Google Apps Script - Events Board date expiry

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-macros

I've been building an Events Board. I want to make it so when events expire on the Events Board, they automatically move to a hidden sheet in the same format.

The layout on my 'Events Board' is:

```
Subject | Start Date | Start Time | End Date | End Time | All Day Event | Description | Location | Private | Free | No Approval Required
```

The hidden sheet is called `Expired Events` and has the same layout as the Events Board.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: It should be pretty simple with a timebased trigger.

Answer (score 1):

**Move expired events to another sheet**

```
function hideExpiredEvents() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Events Board');
  var exsh=ss.getSheetByName('Expired Events');
  var sr=2;
  var rg=sh.getRange(sr,1,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var dt=new Date();
  var  d=0;//deleted row counter
  var today=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate(0)).valueOf();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(new Date(vA[i][3]).valueOf()<today) {
      exsh.appendRow(vA[i]);//move to bottom of expired events
      sh.deleteRow(i+sr-d++);//increment deleted row counter
    }
  }
}
```

Edited

Comment: Thanks so much for posting a solution! It's still throwing up an error when I try to input it at:

'     exsh.appendRow(vA[i]);move to bottom of expired events '

It is showing the error:

Missing ; before statement. (line 136, file "Code")

Comment: Hi there @MichaelMiller, you have to write *//* at the beginning of that English phrase, so it can be ignored by the compiler. It shall look as the following line.

Comment: Sorry about not putting in the comment operator

Comment: So I'm getting a new error now for the code on the line:

  var rg=sh.getRange(sr,1,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,sh.getLastColumn());

TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of Null